# Python substitution with replacement function

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with some SQL like:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (2, 'b');
...
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1000, 'all');
```

And I want to increment in the file all the `ID` values with 1000, to get:

```
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1001, 'a');
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1002, 'b');
...
INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (2000, 'all');
```

I wrote the following Python code

```
import os, re
root = r'path\to\dir'
path = os.path.join(root, 'original.sql')
new =  os.path.join(root, 'new.sql')

def increment(n, base=1000):
    return str(int(n.group(1)) + base)

with open(path) as f, open(new, 'w') as g:
    for line in f:
        line = re.sub('.*VALUES \((\d{1,4}),.*', increment, line)
        g.write(line)
```

but that just outputs the incremented values instead of doing the substitution. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that you are matching and substituting _the entire line_, not just the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
def fix_line(n, base=1000):
    return n.group(1) + str(int(n.group(2)) + base) + n.group(3)

line = re.sub('(.*VALUES \()(\d{1,4})(,.*)', fix_line, line)
```

So if you have `line = "INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (1001, 'a');"` to start, then after your regex substitution you will have:

```
line = "INSERT INTO table (ID, Name) VALUES (2001, 'a');"
```

Basically, you need to capture the stuff before the number and the stuff after the number and include it in your processing of each line.

I should add that you don't need `.*` at the start and the end of your regex.  It will also work with `line = re.sub('(VALUES \()(\d{1,4})(,)', fix_line, line)` though this time you only match a small part of `line`, specifically `VALUES (1001,` and then apply your substitution function on just that and leaving the other parts of the string unchanged.  (Your original regex matched the entire line and regenerated it.).

You could also do

```
def iterate_number(n, base=1000):
    return "VALUES (%d," % (int(n.group(1)) + base)

line = re.sub('VALUES \((\d{1,4}),', iterate_number, line)
```

which only has one matched group (the number), and merely adds back the `VALUES (` before the number, and the comma after the number in the string processing.